# PHP regex for image name with numbers

Tags: php, regex

I have images with names such as:

```
img-300x300.jpg
img1-250x270.jpg
```

These names will be stored in a string variable. My image is in Wordpress so it will be located at e.g.

mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/img-300x300.jpg

and I need the string to be changed to

mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/img.jpg

I need a PHP regular expression which would return img.jpg and img1.jpg as the names.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Addition

Sorry guys, I had tried this but it didn't work

```
$string = 'img-300x300.jpg'
$pattern = '[^0-9\.]-[^0-9\.]';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: You should post what you tried

Comment: **"and I need the string to be changed to  `mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/img.jpg`"**. Are you sure ? because that way can only have 1 image with the same name on that directory.

Comment: Is this solved, or are you still having problems with it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using PHP native functions itself.

```
<?php

function genLink($imagelink)
{
$img1 = basename($imagelink);
$img = substr($img1,0,strrpos($img1,'-')).substr($img1,strpos($img1,'.'));
$modifiedlink = substr($imagelink,0,strrpos($imagelink,'/'))."/".$img;
return $modifiedlink;
}

echo genLink('mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/flower-img-color-300x300.jpg');
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/flower-img-color.jpg
```

Comment: @aelor, They are delimiters for the regular expression.

Comment: Thanks Shankar. My image is in Wordpress so it will be located at e.g.

mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/img-300x300.jpg

and I need the string to be changed to

mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/img.jpg

Comment: Shankar, that is great but it does not seem to work with images that have hyphens in the name e.g. Flower-Image-2-300x500.png - I would need this to be changed to Flower-Image-2.png

Answer (score 1):

You can do that as:

`(img\d*)-([^.]*)(\..*)`

and `\1\3` will contain what you want:

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/vU2mD4

Or, replace `(img\d*)-([^.]*)(\..*)` with `\1\3`

Comment: Hi sshashank124 thanks for your answer. That works, but it does not work with the particular string I am using. My image is in Wordpress so it will be located at e.g. http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/img-300x300.jpg and I need the string to be changed to http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/img.jpg - please help

Comment: @badcoder, I have updated my answer. Please tell me if that works.

Comment: There will be alot of images, all of them will not be called img so e.g. I will have a file http://mysite.server.it/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/flowers-2-500x333.jpg and it needs to be replaced to http://mysite.server.it/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/flowers-2.jpg

Comment: Thanks alot sshashank124!!

Answer (score 0):

May be this?

```
(\w+)-[^.]+?(\.\w+)
```

The `$1$2` will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting question, and since you are using php, it can be nicely solved with a branch reset (a feature of Perl, PCRE and a few other engines).

Search: `img(?|(\d+)-\d{3}x\d{3}|-\d{3}x\d{3})\.jpg`

Replace: `img\1.jpg`

The benefit of this solution, compared with a vague replacement, is that we are sure that we are matching a file whose name matches the format you specified.

Comment: branch what ?? i tried with `img12-300x300.jpg` and it failed

Comment: The correct search pattern should be: `img(?|(\d)-\d{3}x\d{3})\.jpg`

Comment: @aelor It failed because the OP specified `img1-250x270.jpg` with a single digit after img, so this is what I delivered. If you want several, we need to capture `\d+` That might not be a bad thing even if he hasn't requested it, so I'll add that.

Comment: @EduardoVerdugoCáceres Sorry, but that is not correct. The pattern I provided is correct. Yours does not match `img-300x300.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

search : `\-[^.]+`

replace with : `''`

Answer (score 0):

```
(.[^\-]*)(?:.[^\.]*)\.(.*)
```

group 1 - name before "-"

group 2 - extension. (everything after ".")

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is **only** one `-` and one `.` then `explode()` should work great for this:

```
<?php

// array of image names
$images = array();
$images[] = 'img-300x300.jpg';
$images[] = 'img1-250x270.jpg';

// array to store new image names
$new_names = array();

// loop through images
foreach($images as $v)
{
    // explode on dashes
    // so we would have something like:
    // $explode1[0] = 'img';
    // $explode1[1] = '300x300.jpg';
    $explode1 = explode('-',$v);

    // explode the second piece on the period
    // so we have:
    // $explode2[0] = '300x300';
    // $explode2[1] = 'jpg';
    $explode2 = explode('.',$explode1[1]);

    // now bring it all together
    // this translates to
    // img.jpg and img1.jpg
    $new_names[] = $explode1[0].'.'.$explode2[1];
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r($new_names, true).'</pre>';

?>
```